# Explore all object of a list and delete some of them

Tags: python, list

`l`is a list that I want to explore in order to suppress some items. The function `do.i.want.to.suppres.i` returns TRUE or FALSE in order to tell me whether I want the suppression. The details of this function is not important.

I tried this:

```
l = [1,4,2,3,5,3,5,2]
for i in l:
   if do.i.want.to.suppress.i(i):
      del i
print l
```

but `l` does not change! So I tried

```
l = [1,4,2,3,5,3,5,2]
for position,i in enumerate(l):
   if do.i.want.to.suppress.i(i):
      del l[position]
```

But then the problem is that the position does not match the object `i` as `l`get modified during the loop.

I could do something like this:

```
l = [1,4,2,3,5,3,5,2]
for position,i in enumerate(l):
   if do.i.want.to.suppress.i(i):
      l[position] = 'bulls'
l = [x for x in l if x!='bulls']
```

But I guess there should have a smarter solution. Do you have one?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that! Thanks everyone for your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = [item for item in my_list if not do_I_suppress(item)]
```

List comprehensions! learn them! love them! live them!

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension approach is the most pythonic way, but if you really need to modify the list itself then I found this to be the best approach, nicer than the while loop approach:

```
for position in xrange(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):        
    i = l[position]
    if do.i.want.to.suppress.i(i):
        del l[position]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use a while loop

```
i = 0
while i < len(l):
  if do.i.want.to.suppress.i(i):
    del l[i]
  else:
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will also work:

```
answer = filter(lambda x: not do_I_suppress(x), lis)
```

Note that in Python 3.x, you will need to put `filter` in `list`:

```
answer = list(filter(lambda x: not do_I_suppress(x), lis))
```

Comment: -1 cause there is worse than 0 benefit for this approach vs. the list comprehension approach: this creates a function & calls it on each element which is much slower. list comprehensions are just a nicer syntactical way of doing functional programming anyway

Comment: @Claudiu "this creates a function call on each element", exactly as list comprehensions. From `filter()` documentation: `Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item in iterable if function(item)]`. I agree list comprehension is more readable (only because he used `lambda` to negate `do_i_suppress`), but his answer is still valid.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: not "creates a function call on each element", but "creates a function *and* calls it on each element". the `filter` creates a `lambda` and then the lambda is called. the list comprehension doesn't. `python -m timeit "[x for x in xrange(100) if x%2 == 0]"` gives `10000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 usec per loop` while `python -m timeit "filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, xrange(100))"` gives `10000 loops, best of 3: 31.4 usec per loop`, that's a lot slower.

Comment: @Claudiu The example was supposed to have a list and a function already defined, of course generating the list without the undesired items is faster than creating the list and then removing those items... `py -m timeit "def is_even(x): return True if x % 2 == 0 else False; [x for x in range(100) if is_even(x)]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.138 usec per loop` vs `py -m timeit "def is_even(x): return True if x % 2 == 0 else False; filter(is_even, range(100))"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.14 usec per loop`

Comment: @KurzedMetal: my example is the same if you use `xrange` or `range`. the issue is that with the `filter`, you have to declare a function, but with this list comprehension, you don't. it's faster if you don't declare the function. iCodez example here declares a function unnecessarily

Comment: Oh, you confused me.  I thought you were saying it re-created the `lambda` each time, which I thought was incorrect.  Now I understand what you are really saying.

Comment: I see, you are right :) really weird and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (which returns a list, creating the full list in memory):

```
filtered_list = [itm for itm in lst if i_want_to_keep(itm)]
```

You can use [filter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) (same result as List Comprehensions)

```
filtered_list = filter(i_want_to_keep, lst)
```

or [itertools.ifilter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) (which returns an iterator and avoid creating the whole list in memory, specially useful for iterating)

```
import itertools
filtered_list = itertools.ifilter(i_want_to_keep, lst)

for itm in filtered_list:
    do_whatever(itm)
```

Comment: a generator is probably better choice here than `itertools.ifilter` if you're going for that approach